# Do you take a swig "of" or "from" a bottle?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Do you take a swig "of" or "from" a bottle?

I have done some research, but can't find a clear answer to this. Are both correct?

Comment: In the U.S., "swig" is informal (and masculine), but "draught" is almost unheard of. "Drink" and "swallow" and "sip" are frequent and not informal.

Comment: Gulp as well, maybe. Take a pull is rather old fashioned but still understandable.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a swig **of** something (beer, cold tea, water, whatever) **from** a bottle, or just a swig **from** a bottle. The verb 'swig' is informal; draught is more formal in British English.

[Swig (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/swig)